# PDPageContentStream Y-Axis Base

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Apologies if this is a terrible question, but is there any way to tell the PDPageContentStream that 0 on the y-axis is actually the top of the page instead of the bottom?

We have all our coordinates stored that way (e.g. "0,10" is the ten points *down* on the left side of the page) and as we're generating PDFs we're finding countless bugs that are related to broken math around calculating the inverse of the value so that we can call moveTextPositionByAmount().

Thanks in advance!